# Codeigniter session value access

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter, session-variables

I recently bought project management system, I was trying to add new forms but my forms are not working. I think my problem is the model, I am failing to get a session value (project_code) submitted to the database to make sure that the specific entry is visible to the specific project. The system I bought is ekushey available on codecanyon.

**Model**

```
function client_invoicing_add($project_code = '') {
    //$data['project_code'] =   $project_code;
    //$data['project_code'] =   $this->session->userdata('project_code');
    $data['client_payment_milestone']       =   $this->input->post('client_payment_milestone');
    $data['client_payment_deliverables']    =   $this->input->post('client_payment_deliverables');
    $data['client_payment_date']            =   $this->input->post('client_payment_date');
    $data['client_payment_amount']          =   $this->input->post('client_payment_amount');
    $data['timestamp']    = strtotime($this->input->post('timestamp'));
    $data['client_id']    = $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
    $data['project_code'] = $this->db->get_where('project' , array('project_id' => $project_id))->row()->project_code;
    //$data['project_id']   = $this->db->get_where('project' , array('project_code' => $project_code))->row()->project_id;
    $this->db->insert('client_invoicing' , $data);
}
```

**Controller**

```
// Client invoicing
function client_invoicing($param1 = '' , $param2 = '' , $param3 = '') {
    if ($this->session->userdata('client_login') != 1) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('last_page', current_url());
        redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
    }

    if ($param1 == 'add') {
        $this->crud_model->client_invoicing_add($param2); // param2 = project code
    }

    if ($param1 == 'edit') {
        $this->crud_model->client_invoicing_edit($param2); // param2 = client payment id
    }

    if ($param1 == 'delete') {
        $this->crud_model->client_invoicing_delete($param2); // param2 = client payment id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());` to **print all session objects**. and from them you can check if session is already set or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Session array is available through the $_SESSION global:
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        // or:
        $name = $this->session->name
        // or:
        $name = $this->session->userdata('name');

    If you want to retrieve all of the existing userdata
       $_SESSION
       // or:
       $this->session->userdata();
```

> Note : The userdata() method returns NULL if the item you are trying
>   to access does not exist.